# How to add horizontal scroll bars to the layout without affecting other functions?

Tags: python, pyside6

There is also a scroll layout within the scroll layout.

The scrolling layout inside was originally a grid layout, but it was squashed after it was replaced with a scrolling layout. I just want to scroll horizontally, and the vertical direction will remain the same as the vertical layout, automatically stretching to the maximum.

I don't want to set a fixed height. I want this scroll layout to be the same as the original, with automatic vertical resizing.

Is this because of compression caused by the parent layout?

```
for item in json_data:
        group_box = QFrame(frameShape=QFrame.StyledPanel)
        group_layout = QVBoxLayout(group_box)
        group_box.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        group_box.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
            lambda pos, gb=group_box: self.create_group_context_menu(gb).popup(
                gb.mapToGlobal(pos - QPoint(10, 10))))
        tip_frame = QFrame(frameShape=QFrame.StyledPanel)
        tip_layout = QVBoxLayout(tip_frame)
        pair_frame = QFrame(frameShape=QFrame.StyledPanel)
        pair_layout = QVBoxLayout(pair_frame)
        level_frame = QFrame(frameShape=QFrame.StyledPanel)
        level_layout = QVBoxLayout(level_frame)
        group_layout.addWidget(level_frame)
        group_layout.addWidget(tip_frame)
        group_layout.addWidget(pair_frame)
        for key in item.keys():
            button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
            button = QPushButton(key)
            button_layout.addWidget(button)
            # 确定正确的 layout
            current_layout = tip_layout if key == "tip" else pair_layout if key == "pair" else level_layout
            if key == "level":
                level_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
                label = QLineEdit(item[key])
                level_layout.addWidget(label)
            elif key == "pair":
                pair_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
                # 检查pair是否包含多层列表
                if all(isinstance(el, list) for el in item["pair"]):
                    sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                    container = QWidget()  # 创建一个容器
                    grid_layout = QGridLayout(container)  # 直接将容器设置给grid_layout
                    grid_layout.setHorizontalSpacing(39)

                    for col, sub_list in enumerate(item["pair"]):
                        for row, text in enumerate(sub_list):
                            text_edit = QLineEdit(text)
                            text_edit.setMinimumWidth(150)  # 固定文本框长度
                            text_edit.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
                            text_edit.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
                                lambda pos, te=text_edit: self.create_context_menu(te).popup(
                                    te.mapToGlobal(pos - QPoint(10, 10))))
                            grid_layout.addWidget(text_edit, row, col)

                    scroll_area = QScrollArea()
                    scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(False)

                    scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)  # 总是开启水平滚动条
                    scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)  # 关闭垂直滚动条
                    scroll_area.setWidget(container)  # 将装有grid_layout的容器设置到滚动区域
                    scroll_area.setMinimumHeight(150)

                    pair_layout.addWidget(scroll_area)  # 将滚动区域添加到pair_layout
```

Comment: add some code plz

Comment: It seems that there is no such automatic method. The only way is to write code yourself to adjust the length of the internal scroll layout.

Comment: Please provide a comprehensive [mre] and remove anything irrelevant (like signal connections or unreadable comments) that would just make code distracting.